# How can I use HOST VARIABLE in rs.add("host:port") in mongoDB Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset

I am setting up MongoDB Sharded Cluster via Shell script and would like to run

$mongo --port 27027 --eval 'rs.add("$HOSTNAME:27037")'

Is there is way to add RS member via variable instead of hard-coded string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add the host like this:

RS-LAB:PRIMARY> var host = hostname()

RS-LAB:PRIMARY> var port = 27027

RS-LAB:PRIMARY> var hp = host+':'+port

RS-LAB:PRIMARY> printjson(hp)

"vxxxx.domain.com:27027"

RS-LAB:PRIMARY> rs.add(hp)
{
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1530299232, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1530299232, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"BiLMYfYVWTgS+pQeGnZK7+N6Vf8="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6572537789634576385")
        }
    }
}

RS-LAB:PRIMARY>